# Concat Dataframes with matching conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with .csv Dataframes in a directory and want to concat three cases.

1. Length > 0 & "Small_Letters" in the name
2. Length > 0 & "SEO_Update" in the name
3. Length > 0 & "NewTerm" in the name

But how can I access in my directory the names first, compare, enter the dataframe length and concat the matching dataframes?

```
def Concat_Intermed_Dataframes(batchname, changebatch, my_path, filename)
   print("Start concatenating")
   List_For_Concat = os.listdir(os.path.join(my_path, changebatch, batchname, "intermed"))
   for element in List_For_Concat: 
       if "Small_Letters" in element: 
           #concat with next dataframe which also has a length > 0
       elif "SEO_Update" in element: 
           #concat with next dataframe which also has a length > 0
       elif "NewTerm" in element: 
           #concat with next dataframe which also has a length > 0
   return #three dataframes
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have dataframes:

```
selected=[]
for df in dfs:
    names = df.columns.to_list()
    if ("Small_Letters" or "SEO_Update" or "NewTerm") in names and len(names)>0:
        selected.append(df)
```